# navigation flow of kitchensink example in Sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i'm new to sencha touch.i deployed the kitchensink example application successfully.i want to know the navigation flow(from which file to which file) of kitchensink example .can anyone help me? and i didn't found the launch() in app.js.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kitchen Sink is using [profiles](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Profile). It means that the app will be displayed differently depending on what kind of device it is displayed on.

You'll find a `launch` function in `app/profile/Base.js` which will be called anyway and then you'll also find two other `launch` functions in both `app/profile/Phone.js` and `app/profile/Tablet.js`. The former will be called if you launch the app from a phone and the latter from a tablet.

From there it should be pretty straightforward.

Hope this helps